# Invalid or corrupt jarfile ios-server-standalone-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT.jar

Tags: java

I am starting automation with iOS driver and selenium.

I am following http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/?page=setup#launch link.

Installed sdk and jdk.

while starting server with command

```
$ java -jar ios-server-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar -aut Mountains.app -port 4444
```

I am getting following error.

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile ios-server-standalone-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Server is not starting somehow.

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: What version of Java did you install? "The server is written in Java and requires Java 7"

Comment: Thanks for the help!! I will update JDK and then I will try again.